# Observer RMI registry via command line

Tags: java, shell, rmi

I'm currently starting to work with Java RMI and want to look at what bindings my local RMI registry (started by `rmiregistry &` from shell) offers after I've bound my server stubs. Is there a simple way to query all offered bindings from command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `rmiregistry` command does not allow you to view the registry. Instead you can write a simple java program to do this. For example:

```
public class RegistryViewer {
  public static void main(String... args){
    String host = args[0];
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, port);
    for (String name : registry.list()) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: got java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect message